# onSharedPreferenceChanged question

Tags: android, preferenceactivity

is there a way not to save the changes in shared_pref, instead save it to sqlite using

```
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences,String key) 
{
}
```

i can't seem to "intercept" the data, as it is always writing to shared_pref

any inputs would be great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intercept the change with `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener.onPreferenceChange()`, save to sqlite, and return false.

However this *may* cause the visible state of the preference to not change so you may have to update it yourself.

Barry

Comment: cool, that's exactly what i'm looking for. i'll mark it as an answer after 3 mins, as it wont allow me now. thanks again :)